# How to use class in div tag inside asp.net controls InnerHtml c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, innerhtml

I'm trying to use div tag inside innerhtml c#. Below is my piece of code for sample,

```
slideUL.InnerHtml = "<div class = "slide - holder"/>"
```

But I'm getting compile error. Please any one guide me to proceed this.

Comment: What king of control is "slideUL"?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single quote or escape with double quote for class property. I think class name should be without any space like `slide-holder`. Also you have missed close `</div>` tag

```
slideUL.InnerHtml = "<div class = \"slide-holder\"/></div>"
```

Comment: I tried this. But I'm not able to see the expected result.

Comment: @Mostafiz what is different than your previous version? both the same...

Comment: yeah it was, but OP said it is not worked, I guess the class name will be without space like `slide-holder`

Comment: @Mostafiz Yes. Thanks for your response. Still I'm seeing the html content (that I wrote in the server side) in the web page :-(. Anyhow, you gave me the correct answer for the question that I asked. Now I didn't get any compile error.

Comment: @Mostafiz Can I use ul tag in InnerHtml ?

Comment: you can use this HtmlGenericControl https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: and also you can use ul innerhtml too

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use quotation marks, you need to use `escape characters` for them:

`slideUL.InnerHtml = "<div class = \"slide - holder\"/>"`

See this MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx